# Does someone know this "|" operator?

Tags: algorithm, operator-keyword

I found the following algorithm:

[image]

Does someone recognize what is "|" ?

Comment: It is most likely an `OR` operator, i.e. this is saying if `d` or `b` be true, then execute the closure `{ ... }`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i disagree with you - in my opinion it's and OR operator but a bitwise one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen both d and b are integers :(

Comment: I take back what I said.  I think it is the bitwise `OR` operator.

Comment: in C++ like languages `|` is bitwise OR (or corresponding bits together) and `||` is boolean OR (handle operands as single bit true/false)

Comment: It could be "or", "bitwise-or", or something else entirely. This isn't any specific programing language.

Comment: I think it means "divides" (without remainder), in this case. It should be read "if d divides b".

Comment: @thescion I don't see how that refutes my guess. I read it as "if d divides b (without remainder), then do all the stuff within, including operating on b/d and n/d". If it follows from beforehand that n is a multiple of b, I'd be more sure of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In math the operator means:

> For integers m and n, it is said that m divides n, m is a divisor of n, or n is a multiple of m, and this is written as `m|n`.

See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) for further details.

Comment: I think this actually makes sense since this algorithm is under the theory of numbers chapter

Comment: nice but OP is clearly about algorithm so there is only slight chance `|` refers to math terminology

Comment: @Spektre Not really. The OP algorithm's context clearly involves diving `b/d` right after checking if `d` divides `b` and then uses a bunch of number-theory related operations. I find it unlikely to think it's an OR operation. Moreover, if you allow it to be OR, then you can have potentially division-by-zero in the first instruction if `d == 0`.

Comment: @ale64bit language was not specified so it could be anything I saw some crazy scripts where `|` was string operation and used in similar way (convert int to string ... merge them ... convert to int .. and compute) that is why I stated in `C++ like ...` but in this context I suppose you're right but I would not give my hand to fire on that

Comment: @HFR1994: "since this algorithm is under the theory of numbers chapter" - why didn't you indicate in your question where the snippet came from (such as at least the name of the book) so that people would have some context instead of making them guess?